# How to optimize the performance of merge statement when inner query is executing faster in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle19c

target table FUR_FACT_T has around 9 million records. while the inner query returns around 50k records. how to optimize the performance of this merge statement? I tried to put the parallel keyword but nothing seems to be working to optimize the performance

```
MERGE --+ parallel(targ)
INTO FUR_FACT_T targ
           USING (  WITH LATEST_DATA AS
                        (
                    SELECT  ITEM_NO ,
                            ITEM_TYPE   ,
                            CODE_SUP    ,
                            TYPE_SUP    ,
                            CODE_RU ,
                            TYPE_RU ,
                            PERCENT_SHARE,
                            VALID_FROM  ,
                            VALID_TO  ,
                            MAX(VALID_FROM) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_NO,ITEM_TYPE,CODE_SUP,TYPE_SUP,CODE_RU,TYPE_RU) AS MAX_VALID_FROM
                            FROM FUR_FACT_T
                            WHERE (ITEM_NO,ITEM_TYPE,CODE_SUP,TYPE_SUP,CODE_RU,TYPE_RU) IN
                                    (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_NO,ITEM_TYPE,SUP_CODE,SUP_TYPE,SUP_CODE_RAGREE,SUP_TYPE_RAGREE
                                        FROM TEMP.FACT_ITEM_TEMP_T WHERE VER_DELETE_DATE IS NOT NULL 
                                        )
                                    AND date '2023-01-11'  >= VALID_FROM
                                    AND date '2023-01-11'  <= nvl(VALID_TO,DATE '9999-12-31')   
                        )
                        SELECT p.ITEM_NO    ,
                                p.ITEM_TYPE ,
                                p.CODE_SUP  ,
                                p.TYPE_SUP  ,
                                p.CODE_RU   ,
                                p.TYPE_RU   ,
                                p.NO_OF_SEATS,
                                p.PERCENT_SHARE
                FROM ( SELECT * FROM TEMP.FACT_ITEM_DATA_TEMP_T WHERE VER_DELETE_DATE IS NOT NULL) p
                LEFT OUTER JOIN LATEST_DATA q
                ON  p.ITEM_NO         = q.ITEM_NO
                AND p.ITEM_TYPE       = q.ITEM_TYPE
                AND p.CODE_SUP     = q.CODE_SUP
                AND p.TYPE_SUP     = q.TYPE_SUP
                AND p.CODE_RU      = q.CODE_RU
                AND p.TYPE_RU     = q.TYPE_RU
                AND q.VALID_FROM      = q.MAX_VALID_FROM
                WHERE (p.ITEM_NO,p.ITEM_TYPE,p.CODE_SUP,p.TYPE_SUP,p.CODE_RU,p.TYPE_RU) IN
                                    (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_NO,ITEM_TYPE,SUP_CODE,SUP_TYPE,SUP_CODE_RAGREE,SUP_TYPE_RAGREE
                                        FROM TEMP.FACT_ITEM_TEMP_T WHERE VER_DELETE_DATE IS NOT NULL 
                                        )
                   ) src
                ON ( targ.ITEM_NO       = src.ITEM_NO
          AND   targ.ITEM_TYPE          = src.ITEM_TYPE
          AND   targ.CODE_SUP        = src.CODE_SUP
          AND   targ.TYPE_SUP        = src.TYPE_SUP
          AND   targ.CODE_RU         = src.CODE_RU
          AND   targ.TYPE_RU         = src.TYPE_RU
          AND   targ.VALID_FROM         = src.VALID_FROM)
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
                targ.PERCENT_SHARE         = src.PERCENT_SHARE,
                targ.VALID_TO               = src.VALID_TO ;
```

Comment: looks like you could just remove the entire source subquery and replace it with your subquery involving `TEMP.FACT_ITEM_TEMP_T`, since you aren't referencing your any of the `latest_data` columns in the outer select, and the join is an outer join. You might need to include predicates that check the `p.ITEM_NO,p.ITEM_TYPE,p.CODE_SUP,p.TYPE_SUP,p.CODE_RU,p.TYPE_RU` columns are not nullable, unless they're part of the primary key on TEMP.FACT_ITEM_DATA_TEMP_T.

Comment: And when you say `nothing seems to be working`, you should include what that is. We can't know what you've tested, and might be missing something obvious, like indexing the fields used in joins

Answer (score 0):

**Parallelism**

The current query is probably not using any parallelism. The hint is using object-level parallelism, where parallelism is only applied to the specified object - . It's usually better to use statement-level parallelism, which parallelizes every part of the query. Replace the hint `--+ parallel(targ)` with `--+ parallel` to enable statement-level parallelism.

But parallelism by default does not apply to modified tables, since modifying objects in parallel can be dangerous since the entire table will be locked and the changes may be unrecoverable if there's a disaster. If you're willing to accept those risks, run a statement like this in your session:

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
```

Note that parallelism will only make your query work harder, not smarter. No matter what you do, you'll want to generate an execution plan to ensure the execution plan is sensible.

**Generic execution plan advice**

One of the first step in performance tuning is to find out precisely what is slow. Since this appears to be a large data warehouse query, you'll want to generate the [execution plan](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan#gather_plan_statistics_hint) which will show you the *actual* rows and times instead of merely estimates. Add that execution plan as text to the question and you may be able to get more detailed help.